# How to use fetch() API in React to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to write a component in React that will use the fetch() API to get data from a website, then use setState to set a state equal to the data, and then finally render the data. My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {apiInfo: 'default'};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent').then(
            function(response){
                return response.json();
            }
            ).then(function(jsonData){
                return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            }
            ).then(function(jsonStr){
                this.setState({apiInfo: jsonStr});
                console.log(jsonStr);
            });
    }

    render(){
        return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.state.apiInfo}</td>
                </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

However, this results with an error saying I'm unable to setState of undefined. I end up rendering 'default' on my HTML. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try to pass an arrow function to .then

Comment: Hey there! So this worked, but could you explain why the arrow function would make such a big difference? I thought the only difference for the arrow function and functions was that arrow functions weren't hoisted?

Comment: The arrow function binds this to declaration context instead of execution context.

Comment: For more explanation look at mdn [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) page in "No separate this" section

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your error message is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> unable to setState of undefined

So you're trying call `setState` as a method of an object that doesn't exist at that point.  As a property of what object are you trying to call `setState` as a method?

> this.setState({apiInfo: jsonStr});

Yes, it's your `this` that's the problem.  At the point that you're trying to call it - i.e. inside a `.then()` of a `fetch` call - `this` is actually undefined.  You can see this in the Chrome Devtools:

[image: Chrome Devtools shows this=undefined]
I'm afraid that `this` is a slippery customer in JavaScript; its value can (and does) change depending upon the current context of your app.

There's several ways you can workaround this.  One slightly clunky (but it works!) way is to capture your `this` value before you enter your .fetch() call, and assign it to another variable.  You'll often see `that` or `self` variables used for this purpose, but they're just conventions.  You can call the variable what you like.

Here's how I've reworked your componentDidMount() method capturing `this` to `that`, and calling `that` inside the `.then()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    fetch("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent")
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData) {
            return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        })
        .then(function(jsonStr) {
            that.setState({ apiInfo: jsonStr });
            console.log(jsonStr);
        });
}
```

If you're comfortable using arrow functions, then another way is to replace your "normal" function call with one, like so:

```
.then(jsonStr => {
    this.setState({ apiInfo: jsonStr });
    console.log(jsonStr);
});
```

An arrow function's `this` is always the `this` that its parent defined.

Comment: OH ok thank you for the explanation! I saw the solutions about using the arrow functions and wasn't quite sure until I saw this. Could you elaborate a little bit more on what 'this' would be referring to within the fetch() API if I didn't use the arrow function? Would it be the global object here?

Answer (score 3):

It is saying `setState` is undefined because you're accessing it in the wrong context. You can either, convert the function into an arrow function or bind it to the right context. [Here](http://When%20and%20why%20do%20we%20bind%20this%20to%20the%20React%20component%20method) is an article as to When and why do we bind this to the React component method.

In your code, the change that can be made is either binding it

```
.then(function(jsonStr){
          this.setState({apiInfo: jsonStr});
          console.log(jsonStr);
      }.bind(this));
```

or using arrow function

```
.then((jsonStr)=>{
          this.setState({apiInfo: jsonStr});
          console.log(jsonStr);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

- `this` refers to the object which calls the function.
- every normal function has its own `this` however arrow functions does not (`this` here refers to the outside context i.e., what `this` is outside the function.).

So the possible solutions are

- Use Arrow function

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent').then(
            function(response){
                return response.json();
            }
            ).then(function(jsonData){
                return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            }
            ).then(function(jsonStr){
                this.setState({apiInfo: jsonStr});
                console.log(jsonStr);
            });
}
```

- save `this` in some other variable earlier and pass it as argument.
- Bind `this` to the function

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Write the fetch code into separate method, then you will be able to call this.setState({}) inside the ".then(..)" statement after adding a bind to the new function inside the constructor.

Example:

```
constructor(props){
     super(props)
     ...
     this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this)
}

myFunc = () => {
    fetch('...')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => this.setState({ apiInfo: data }));
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.myFunc()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ apiInfo: data }));
  }
```

In your render function you cannot just do `this.state.apiInfo`. This data is an array of objects, each object has keys like `username` `img` and more. You can see that if you `console.log(this.state.apiInfo)` inside the `render` function and outside the `return`.

To access and display the each object inside of the arrays values you can `map` through your  `apiInfo` array.

```
render() {
const { apiInfo } = this.state;
apiInfo && console.log(apiInfo.map(item => item.img));
return (
  <div>
    {apiInfo &&
      apiInfo.map(item =>  <div> {item.img} </div> )}
  </div>
);
}
```

The native fetch API that comes with the browser uses JavaScript promises to resolve the asynchronous response.

When the data is fetched successfully, it will be stored in the local state with React’s this.setState() method. Then the render() method will trigger again and you can display the fetched data.

Arrow functions were introduced in ES6, and an arrow function does not have its own context and will instead use the same `this` as the context in which it was defined. We can use this fact and pass in an arrow function to the callback.

Comment: it is an array of objects i console logged it