# How do I use data from a Fetch request in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to access an API, and present the data in a graph.  I have followed tutorials on using Fetch; for example this one:
(https://appdividend.com/2018/08/20/javascript-fetch-api-example-tutorial/)

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/KrunalLathiya')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Which is lovely, it fetches the data and logs it into the console.  But from what I can tell, the data is not available externally, how do I get the data displaying inside `console.log(json)` , into the state, so I can then present it in a graph?

Comment: How in your React application do you usually update the state of your component? Disregarding `fetch()` for a moment, if you are unsure about how to update state, it may be good to consider going through the basic React [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) first before continuing.

Comment: This question is really broad. But in general, if you're in a react element, surely you can get the result of the fetch operation and just called `this.setState({})`, the same as you would for any other react state change...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use fetch() API in React to setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684217/how-to-use-fetch-api-in-react-to-setstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Katia Wheeler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2832346/katia-wheeler) is correct. If you want to stay with the Promise only. Then inside you second `then` where you have your `console.log` you can use `this.setState`.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/KrunalLathiya')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  this.setState({
    graphData: json,
  })
});
```

Then you will have it in the component state and you can use it normally from there.

Comment: Wonderful,  a few words of advice to those who might read this in the future:

a) use a class, rather than a functional component, so you have an internal state to set.
b) set the state to some default values beforehand, to display whilst the API call is processing, in this example, I used  ```state = {
    graphData: [{ x:0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }]
  };```
c) you should then be able to access the data using ```this.state.graphData```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the response to a variable and then call `setState` with the data like so:

**UPDATED WITH ASYNC**

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/KrunalLathiya')
.then(res => res.json());

this.setState({
    data: response
});
```

Then you can access your response using `this.state.data` in render for the graph.

Comment: Updated the answer with `await`ing the asynchronous call